# Can different traversals be identical for one binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to ascertain whether it is possible for the following two traversals to be indentical for a single binary tree:

In-order traversal / Post-order traversal

In-order traversal / Pre-order traversal

Are the two below examples that I put together examples of binary trees? From my understanding, they would be skewed trees, unbalananced and functionally useless, but binary trees nonetheless.

```
              1        in-order traversal: 3, 2, 1
             /         post-order traversal: 3, 2, 1
            2
           /
          3


         1            in-order traversal: 1, 2, 3
          \           pre-order traversal: 1, 2, 3
           2
            \
             3
```

Comment: Yes, those are binary trees.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in some cases (like the examples you gave), different traversals will give the same result. They are different in approach, but that does not mean they will give different results for any input.

Comment: Thank you. What other cases could there be? Or still a skewed tree, but with more nodes?